# GCP Audit Logs regex for path matching

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to create a Pub/Sub log sink on GCP.  Ideally, my Audit Log filter would pick up any CSV files in a specific GCS path, which is given in the logs as `protoPayload.resourceName` when an object is uploaded, the path looking like `projects/_/buckets/<bucket_name>/objects/<path>/<to>/test.csv`*.  The file I'm dropping in the path is called `test.csv`, and the following regex audit log query (i.e. the exact file name) *works* at picking the upload event up:

`protoPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/<bucket_name>/objects/<path>/<to>/test.csv"`

however, the following *actual* regex wildcarding is not picking it up.  Any help is appreciated.

`protoPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/<bucket_name>/objects/<path>/<to>/*.csv"`

**`<bucket_name>` and `/<path>/<to>/` are correctly passed with their real values in query*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ading . before the wildcard (.*)

jsonPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/test_bucket/objects/paht/to/.*.csv"

Tried to recreate on my end and it works well.

Sample query i used:

```
jsonPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/test_bucket/objects/paht/to/.*.csv"
jsonPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/test_bucket/objects/paht/to/sample1.*.csv"
jsonPayload.resourceName =~ "projects/_/buckets/test_bucket/objects/paht/to/test.*.csv"
```

[image: Regex 1]
[image: Regex 2]
[image: Regex 3]